# Magento language and currency switcher not showing whats going on?

Tags: magento

Im hvaign an issue with the currency switcher and language switcher for my theme, I have got two stores a US store and a UK store, as you can see from the image below:

[image]

Ive got my currency setup that imports current rates via webservicex

[image]

Ive got both the language and currency enabled for the default config and its ticked to use default throughout each store view

[image]

Ive also got 2 home pages one for US and one for UK see below:

[image]

, my theme is BlackNWhite Magento theme which supports the language and currency switcher, but for some reason it will not show on my home page I've checked the styles incase its been hidden and Ive cleared the cache several times and still no change, has anyone got any answers to this, I've also checked the theme header files to see if it was commeneted out and its not, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Layout.xml file availble here http://www.filedropper.com/localcopy

Comment: Can you share the layout XML file from your theme that references the switcher? You may need to debug the layout handles to ensure that the switcher is included.

Comment: added my layout file see here - http://www.filedropper.com/localcopy

Comment: You have to select more then one currency for display it in frontend for both the site from configuration.

Comment: when in currency setup I've selected both currency for the default config and in each store I've selected just the currency required. do I have to elect both gbp and usb for each store view ? Edit: I added dollar and pound to the store and now it appears on the front thanks, only thing now is the language between eng & us will that switch store views when i select a different language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED, realized that my stores where actually 2 separate stores rather then being one website, one store, with 2 store views, this is what its supposed to be setup like:

[image]